# I sudo'd a bash script, full of sudo apt-get install applicationname commands, and now my programs won't run

Tags: permissions, software-installation, scripts, 14.10

I sudo'd a bash script, full of sudo apt-get install applicationname commands, and now my programs won't run, unless they are ran as sudo (BAD IDEA!)

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: I've done many installs via scripts and never had your problems, what happens if you run the program from a terminal **without** sudo?

Comment: Post the script.

Comment: http://ibin.co/1cJILIm4X6ia Alvar; atm, dpkg is completely broken. I can't run anything.

Comment: Please run: `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y; apt-get install -f; apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: its not working. Its failing on every package, same error in the screenshot.

Comment: I'm not sure that questions about development releases (based on your screenshot you appear to be using 14.10) are considered on-topic here. FWIW there appear to be several related bug reports e.g. [lilypond-doc: Broken usage of dpkg-maintscript-helper](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=758787)

Comment: What error do you get with just: **`sudo apt-get install -f`** ?

Comment: Try removing `lilypond-doc`: `sudo apt-get remove lilypond-doc`, if that fails, `dufo dpkg --remove lilypond-doc`. Whoever wrote that script doesn't know that `apt` uses regular expressions and not wildcards. Replace the `*` with `.*` if you ever run the script again.

Comment: I agree with muru that the script is not well written. apt-get will take a package list and I would tend to advise against using wild cards, apt will pull in dependencies and IMO it is best to specify what packages you want. wild cards tend to cause unpredictable results.

Comment: @muru yes, and quote them. Otherwise `package.*` is first expanded by the shell, and passed to `apt` only if it does not expand to any file in the current directory (I find that the `zsh` behavior of throwing an error is much better here).

Comment: These are all good suggestions. Unfortunately I reinstalled my OS (well it works now, so its not so unfortunate). Should I delete this question or leave it open?